# Get the names of all virtual machines in an azure scale set via the Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

How do I get a list of all the names of VMs in a scale set via the Python SDK?

I think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_12_01.models.virtualmachinescalesetnetworkprofile?view=azure-python) might have the answer, but I cant create an instance of the class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `virtual_machine_scale_set_vms.list(rg,name)` to list all of the instance name. See this [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_03_30.operations.virtualmachinescalesetvmsoperations?view=azure-python#azure_mgmt_compute_v2017_03_30_operations_VirtualMachineScaleSetVMsOperations_list).

For example:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient, SubscriptionClient

# Tenant ID for your Azure Subscription
TENANT_ID = 'tenat id'

# Your Service Principal App ID
CLIENT = 'client id'

# Your Service Principal Password
KEY = 'client secret'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = CLIENT,
    secret = KEY,
    tenant = TENANT_ID
)

subscription_id = 'subscription_id'


compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

rg = 'shuivmss'
name = 'shuivmss1'
vmss = compute_client.virtual_machine_scale_set_vms.list(rg,name)
for i in vmss:
    print i.name
```

Comment: is there a way if list all vm's in all scale set in the resource group ?